# How to populate select options when we have objects

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, wordpress

I have made a query which is returning data from database using ajax now I have checked the response and I am getting response in the following format.

```
array(206) {
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#6707 (8) {
["id"]=>
string(1) "8"
["year"]=>
string(4) "1947"
["make"]=>
string(7) "Ferrari"
["model"]=>
string(5) "125 S"
["seats"]=>
string(1) "2"
["engine_type"]=>
string(1) "V"
["engine_i"]=>
string(3) "1.5"
["engine_cylinder"]=>
string(2) "12"
}
[1]=>
object(stdClass)#6708 (8) {
["id"]=>
string(1) "9"
["year"]=>
string(4) "1947"
["make"]=>
string(7) "Ferrari"
["model"]=>
string(5) "159 S"
["seats"]=>
string(1) "2"
["engine_type"]=>
string(1) "V"
["engine_i"]=>
string(3) "1.9"
["engine_cylinder"]=>
string(2) "12"
 }
}
```

How can I populate these fields in se`lect options the code I have written till now looks something like this.

```
$('#cq-select-model').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/ferrari_hub/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {action: 'getPopulateField'},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var $year = $('#car-years');
            var $make = $('#car-makes');
            var $model = $('#car-models');
            $year.find('option').remove();
            $make.find('option').remove();
            $model.find('option').remove();
            for (var i in data) {
                $year.append('<option value=' + data[i].year + '>' + 
                data[i].year + '</option>');
                $make.append('<option value=' + data.data[i].make + '>' + 
                data.data[i].make + '</option>');
                $model.append('<option value=' + data[i].model + '>' + 
                data[i].model + '</option>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But it is not populating these fields can someone please help me populating these fields. It will be a great help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The response you're showing seems to be a `var_dump` you should probably return a format that JavaScript can work with better like JSON.

Comment: Also, what `console.log(data);` shows you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Parse the data in JSON format and process.

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/ferrari_hub/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {action: 'getPopulateField'},
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                var result = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(result);
                var $year = $('#car-years');
                var $make = $('#car-makes');
                var $model = $('#car-models');
                $year.find('option').remove();
                $make.find('option').remove();
                $model.find('option').remove();
                for (var i in result) {
                    $year.append('<option value=' + result[i].year + '>' + 
                    result[i].year + '</option>');
                    $make.append('<option value=' + result[i].make + '>' + 
                    result[i].make + '</option>');
                    $model.append('<option value=' + result[i].model + '>' + 
                    result[i].model + '</option>');
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Nope, `for (var in )` is a legal loop.

Comment: Yes parsing the data to Json format solved my problem thank you for that

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but you can probably use the `Option` constructor to create the option rather than concatenating a string. [See here for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option)

The model was using `data.data[i]` but the others were using `data[i]` ~ which looked inconsistent, so assuming the response is json perhaps this might be of use?

```
$('#cq-select-model').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/ferrari_hub/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {action: 'getPopulateField'},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);

            var $year = $('#car-years');
            var $make = $('#car-makes');
            var $model = $('#car-models');

            $year.find('option').remove();
            $make.find('option').remove();
            $model.find('option').remove();

            for ( var n in data ) {
                var obj=data[ n ];

                $year.append( new Option( obj.year, obj.year ) );
                $make.append( new Option( obj.make, obj.make ) );
                $model.append( new Option( obj.model, obj.model ) );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This solution works for me actually the other method with which I was doing it was also correct the only issue that was breaking it was that I was not parsing the data into Json format. Thank you for giving me hint of Json